# Xcode OSX, bind NSString to UILabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a Model Class like this:

Header:

```
@interface RTSecurityModel : NSObject
{
    NSString *code;
}

@property NSString *code;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation RTSecurityModel

@synthesize code;

@end
```

Then I have my App Delegate:

Header:

```
@interface RTAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    RTSecurityModel *security;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property RTSecurityModel *security;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation RTAppDelegate

@synthesize security;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    security = [[RTSecurityModel alloc] init];
    security.code = @"test";
}
```

Then in my MainMenu.xib I've create a label and in the Bindings Inspector set "Bind To: App Delegate" with "Model Key Path: security.code".

But nothing is showing when I'm starting my application.

I tried soooo many ways to bind this variable, but no one gave success.

Please help me not to hate XCode and Cocoa!

**UPD**: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C/A_3381-Simple-Binding-Cocoa-GUI-Application-without-Outlets.html

Here is the sample how to set Property and Label value by editing the Text Field

But is there a way to edit Label without editing the Text Field? Or without Text Field at all?

**UPD2**:

You must not create another instance of Object

```
security = [[RTSecurityModel alloc] init]; // Kill this
```

**Many many thanks to Viktor Lexington**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `security.code` as the model path use `code`. Use the class `RTSecurityModel` in the value section of the bindings tab instead of the AppDelegate.

[Here](http://www.midwinter-dg.com/resources.html) is a demo project.

Do **not** bind the `Text Field Cell`, use the `Text Field`.

You can check if a value is null if you fill the `Null Placeholder` with text, will it show that text instead? Then in time of binding the value it null.

To see your `RTSecurityModel` in the Interface Builder you must let it know your class, it won't look for it.

Add an Object and then set the custom class of it to `RTSecurityModel`.
Then you can choose this object and set the referencing outlet to the property in the App Delegate.
Assignment will now be directly reflected in the label.

[image]

---

I can think of two ways to solve this programmatically without Interface Builder:

1. [Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)

   ```
   // add an observer for the value on the object that has the method below implemented
   [self addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"security.code" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: NULL];

   // method will be called when the observer has 'seen' a value change
   -(void) observeValueForKeyPath: (NSString *)keyPath ofObject: (id) object                  change: (NSDictionary *) change context: (void *) context {
       label.text = ...
   }
   ```
2. Use a custom setter for `code` (`@synthesize` will still create the getter for you)

   ```
   - (void)setCode:(NSString *)aString {
       label.text = aString;
   }
   ```

Comment: oh my God, I did think, that Cocoa Bindings was created to avoid coding at all… But it seems not to be so :(

Comment: @SergeVelikanov Oh ok you only want to create the binding in Interface Builder. Maybe Model Key Path is the wrong field. Have you tried the value field?

Comment: it goes something like this: http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/08/10/261/e8d/886e1ee15c0f84a2b72f400891f1c7a245a76cd9.jpg

Comment: @SergeVelikanov I tried it out and it worked. Updated the answer. You need to change binding target to the RTSecurityModel class.

Comment: thank you very much, Viktor! but I can't see RTSecurityModel in bindings tab :( http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/08/10/b42/3c5/73da0cc543ce4deeff1c98e3c0f3013d41791e64.jpg

Comment: @SergeVelikanov Yeah you have to add an object and set the type to the object to the custom one. Updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59055/discussion-between-serge-velikanov-and-viktor-lexington).